# PHP: Image type does not get recognized

Tags: php

I have a website running on a server with **PHP 5.1.6.1.**

When I try to upload a picture I get the error message that the image type is not supported, although it definitely is party of the allowed image types. Here comes my code:

```
$imgUrl = $_POST['imgUrl'];
$imgInitW = $_POST['imgInitW'];
$imgInitH = $_POST['imgInitH'];
$imgW = $_POST['imgW'];
$imgH = $_POST['imgH'];
$imgY1 = $_POST['imgY1'];
$imgX1 = $_POST['imgX1'];
$cropW = $_POST['cropW'];
$cropH = $_POST['cropH'];

$jpeg_quality = 100;

$output_filename = "../uploads/users/croppedImg_".rand();

$what = getimagesize($imgUrl);
switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $type = '.png';
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $type = '.jpeg';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $type = '.gif';
        break;
    default: die('image type not supported');
}
```

For example, if I want to upload a jpg-file I get the message "image type not supported".

WHAT IS SURPRISING: Running the website on a different server with PHP 5.3.29 does NOT yield any problems and here the image upload works perfectly.

What may be the reason for PHP not correctly recognizing the image type? Is it because of the PHP version which is 5.1.6.1?

Comment: There is no reason at all to still be using php 5.1 which died **8 years** ago. So it would surprise me if that's the culprit, but you should not even be bothering checking whether that is the case, but rather update

Comment: well, did you debug what the output of `strtolower($what['mime'])` is? it's not inconceivable that `getimagesize()` has changed between 5.1.6 and 5.3.29 :)

Answer (score -1):

```
        <?php 
$imgUrl = $_GET['imgUrl'];

$jpeg_quality = 100;



$what = getimagesize($imgUrl);
switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $type = '.png';
        echo "string";
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $type = '.jpeg';
        echo "string";
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $type = '.gif';
        echo "string";
        break;
    default: die('image type not supported');
}
?>
```

Go to : http:// localhoost~/test/image.php?imgUrl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Junonia_lemonias_DSF_upper_by_Kadavoor.JPG

it's working...